# Handling dispose on a COM+ component written in C#

Tags: c#, com, vb6, dispose, finalizer

So, what I am doing at this point is rewriting a vb6 class into C#. The end result is that it will be used as a COM+ component.

Let's assume that we have a logging class that is set up as a COM+ component. From vb6, you use it like this:

```
Set logger = CreateObject("LoggingComponent")
```

I rewrote it in C#, installed the C# class as a COM+ Component and I can use it from vb6. Everything is good at this point. My question comes next.

In order to write the logs in the file, you must call a Flush() method that does the actual write. Until now, the messages are in a Queue in memory. My problem is what happens when I forget to call the Flush method. In vb6, they get flushed. In C#, they do not get flushed. Now comes the difference:

In the original vb6 code, there is a method

```
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Flush()
End Sub
```

I assume this one makes sure that even if we don't call flush, the logs get written.

In C#, I implemented the IDisposable & a destructor, but they don't get called when the vb6 app finishes and disposes the COM+ logger instance (please ignore the missing {} and other useless details, I removed them just to make the code easier to read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
public void Dispose()
     Flush(); // does not get called


~Logger()
     Flush(); // does not get called
```

So...does anyone know what am I missing ? Why the ~Logger does not get called in this scenario ? Is there any COM+ event that I can handle (like Application.Current.Exit event).

Comment: Unlike in VB6, in C#, object disposal is not deterministic. Look at the docs on garbage disposal.

Comment: @JimMack Yes, I know. But knowing this does not actually help me, as I need to fix the issue. Also, I thought that the disposal is done at a certain point in time, we just cannot predict it. What I am seeing is that the destructor does not get called at all.

Comment: How have you tested that they don't get destructed? Just waiting isn't a sufficient test.

Comment: @MichaelGunter Well, the logs don't get written. What other way is there to test it besides having some code that does not get executed ?

Comment: That's not a test. The garbage collector may never have run. Can you add some code with a timer to force GC?

Comment: @MichaelGunter so, I have added a timer that calls GC.Collect(), and it seems that now the destructor gets called. Thanks for the idea. The question still remains if there is a better option, other than calling GC.Collect().

Comment: If the root cause is "forgetting" to call flush manually, that seems like the simplest fix. Calling the GC seems like a kludge and could it have unwanted side effects? (Like a performance hit?)

Comment: Another thought - how important is it to cache the log data in memory and only write it out late? Assuming your `logger` object has some method you call to tell it what to log, why not just call `Flush()` every time at that point? Then this issue goes away.

Comment: @DaveInCaz Well, this is a rewrite from vb6 to C#..and there are a few applications that use that logging, and I can't be sure that when they were developed, they did not forgot to call Flush(); The impact of GC.Collect() should not be too big, since the graph of objects will be pretty small. And also, the queue is to avoid writing too often to HDD / SQL. Write once many logs, to avoid killing on of them.

Comment: @AndreiNeagu Yes, you have to use some kind of `try`-`finally` (or `using`) in the caller code which would release the COM object (presumably using `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject()`).

Comment: @sharptooth The code that uses it is out of my reach. That is existing code, and I can't predict how they used it. That try finally works, but not in my scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's original problem is that GC wasn't running. One option is to build a timer that regularly calls `GC.Collect`. This is probably the safest solution.

I can offer an alternative solution. This solution involves major hackery, and so the developer should beware of this approach. I have not thoroughly vetted this. Simple testing with a COM out-of-process server (not using COM+ here) proved that this approach basically works, but I have not spent the time necessary to research and test that it completely works. Feel free to explore this idea further, but without additional research and testing, *I DO NOT RECOMMEND YOU DO THIS*.

The idea is to swap out the `Release` method in the vtable of the underlying `IUnknown` object with a method of our own creation, so that we can watch when the ref count reaches 0.

```
// !!! THIS CODE INVOLVES A SERIOUS HACK !!!
// !!! USE AT YOUR OWN RISK              !!!

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid(...)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IMyInterface))]
public class MyObject : IMyInterface, IDisposable
{
    // constructor
    public MyObject()
    {
        // get and store this object's IUnknown* (this adds a reference)
        _pUnknown = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(this);

        // get a pointer to the vtable of the IUnknown
        _pVTable = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(_pUnknown);

        // get a pointer to the Release method from the vtable
        var pRelease = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(_pVTable, 2 * IntPtr.Size);

        // get and store a delegate to the original Release method
        _originalRelease = (ReleaseDelegate) Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pRelease, typeof(ReleaseDelegate));

        // set the entry for the Release method in the vtable to a pointer for the ReleaseOverride method
        var pReleaseOverride = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(OverriddenRelease);
        Marshal.WriteIntPtr(_pVTable, 2 * IntPtr.Size, pReleaseOverride);
    }

    // this method will be called when a COM client releases
    private static int ReleaseOverride(IntPtr pUnknown)
    {
        // get the object being released
        var o = (MyObject) Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(pUnknown);

        // call the original release method
        var refCount = o._originalRelease(pUnknown);

        // if the remaining reference count is 1, the only
        // outstanding reference is the reference acquired through
        // the Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject call in the constructor
        if (refCount == 1)
        {
            // call Dispose
            o.Dispose();

            // restore the original Release method
            var pRelease = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(o._originalRelease);
            Marshal.WriteIntPtr(o._pVTable, 2 * IntPtr.Size, pRelease);

            // release the reference we acquired in the constructor
            refCount = Marshal.Release(o._pUnknown);
        }

        // return the ref count
        return refCount;
    }

    // this method will now be called when all COM clients release
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    // the IUnknown pointer for this object
    private readonly IntPtr _pUnknown;

    // a pointer to the v-table of the IUnknown
    private readonly IntPtr _pVTable;

    // a delegate to the original Release method
    private readonly ReleaseDelegate _originalRelease;

    // a delegate to the ReleaseOverride method
    private static readonly ReleaseDelegate OverriddenRelease = ReleaseOverride;

    // the Release delegate type
    private delegate int ReleaseDelegate(IntPtr pUnknown);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try this on Monday and let you know if it worked. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: So, I tested it today. One thing, this has to look like this : _originalRelease = (FuncDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pRelease, typeof(FuncDelegate));. It does not allow Generic Types. Second, it works fine the first time. The second time, I get a StackOverflow exception here : var refCount = o._originalRelease(pUnknown); I am assuming that the original pointer get overwritten with that ReleaseOverride pointer, so it ends up calling itself. I will leave the version with GC.Collect, but this seems to be on the right path. Thanks for your effort

Comment: Aha! I was upgrading some old code to post this answer, and I didn't test it after switching to generic delegates. Thanks.

Comment: RE: The stack overflow. This may have been a bug in my post. (Or otherwise it implies that .NET is reusing the COM objects that underly .NET object instances.) I have updated my post to restore the original Release function pointer before calling the final release.

Comment: If you have the time and patience, I'd love to know if this works for you.

Comment: I managed only today to test it, and it seems to work properly. I did some small updates, as it did not compile, and I also updated the code that you posted. Thanks for your help. I will probably en up using the GC.Collect version, as it is a bit less "hack-ish".

Comment: Happy to see that it "works". Was there a bug in the code from my answer? I don't see your edits. I'd like to at least address any bugs so that anyone else might have a decent starting point for their own experimentation.

Comment: They weren't actually bugs, just compilation issues. I guess the guys who reviewed my edits did not read my comments, in which I said that the changes made are just to make the code compile...Anyway, 1 - I removed the static from ReleaseOverride (check 2 to see why), so you no longer need OverrideRelease member. 2- pVTable is not defined in ReleaseOverride, and to define it, you need the "this", so the method cannot be static.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks. I have updated. A couple of things: In order for a function pointer to a delegate to work correctly, the delegate must not be GC'd. This is why it's necessary to store the delegate. I'm not sure about changing `ReleaseOverride` to non-static because the `this` member is actually passed in via the parameter (as an `IntPtr`). Note that the first line of `ReleaseOverride` resolves that pointer to the .NET object, so any references to non-static fields can use that variable.